# What else is needed to create new tab for content in extension?

Tags: wordpress, extension

I am new to writing an extension.

I add a tab in my contact with this example

```
function civitest_civicrm_tabs( &$tabs, $contactID ) {

  // unset the contribition tab, i.e. remove it from the page
  unset( $tabs[1] );

  // let's add a new "contribution" tab with a different name and put it last
  // this is just a demo, in the real world, you would create a url which would
  // return an html snippet etc.
  $url = CRM_Utils_System::url( 'civicrm/contact/view/contribution', "reset=1&snippet=1&force=1&cid=$contactID" );
  $tabs[] = array( 'id' => 'mySupercoolTab', 'url' => $url, 'title' => 'Contribution Tab Renamed', 'weight' => 300 );
}
```

What should be the next step to add a content in the tab?

how I have to use the extension and add where I have to create a new file to show all the content.

Please can you provide me an example

Thank You

Comment: Are you writing an extension, or... ?

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more. In general, civi will always pick a specific template for a specific url (i.e. the url -> template mapping is fixed and deterministic)

Comment: Hi Nilda, please post the same question only once. You can edit it if you want to change something.

Answer (score 1):

As the example says, "you would create a url which would return an html snippet".

Since this is in the context of a CiviCRM extension, please see the Civix documentation for [how to create a basic page.](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addabasicwebpage)

The url of your tab should be whatever you decide the url of that page should be.

Comment: I create an extension, but my new tab doesn't redirect to another page.  my xml file is in the same file as my hook.  My hook is develop as a plugin and my extension folder is in files/civicrm.